# java .wav playback fails after multiple playbacks

Tags: java, url, audio, clip

I have a .wav file I am trying to play. I am using this code:

```
public static synchronized void play(String path) {     
    try {
        URL soundUrl = SoundTools.class.getResource(path);
        AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundUrl);
        AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(stream);
        clip.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code works well for a while, but after around 30 playbacks, I get a `javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException`. The error message says `unable to obtain a line`. I believe that this has something to do with the system resources, but I do not know how I would go about fixing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException : What am I getting this exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852254/javax-sound-sampled-lineunavailableexception-what-am-i-getting-this-exception)

Comment: @Marv I agree, they look similar, but my error message says `unable to obtain a line`, while his error says `line with format...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never closing the `Clip` which is a subclass of `Line` that why you are receiving this error. Close the clip once you are done using `close` method(that way you can free the resources)  like this

```
clip.close();
```