# javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException In CodeNameOne

Tags: java, mobile, codenameone

I have got this Voice Recording code from CodeNameOne's official website, here's the code.

({https://pastebin.com/FsLmMK2b})

When I record my voice for the 1st time, everything seems fine and I can hear a playback of it but when I try to record for the 2nd time, I can't hear the playback and an exception generates:

Exception: javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException - line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame,  not supported.

[image]

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't thrown by Codename One, it's thrown by Java Sound. Based on the answer to this question: [javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException : Why am I getting this exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852254/javax-sound-sampled-lineunavailableexception-why-am-i-getting-this-exception)

It seems that 24 bit only works for Java on Linux/Mac and on the devices. Use 16 to work on Windows too. It seems that this is true also in the other direction and 1 bit frames are probably unsupported on Windows.

Comment: Thank you very much, Shai for your response! So that surely means I can't use that code since it's not compatible with windows? Or should I edit a specific line?

Comment: You just need to tune the variables. Notice that this is an advanced low level API for Audio processing. You might be served better with an API like `Capture` etc